# QObject set/get property with index operator

Tags: c++, qt, properties, operator-keyword

Why didn't Qt set/get properties through the index operator [] ?
Is there any good reason for this that I don't know about?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any clear benefit to using the indexing operator, but here is a major downside:

Qt objects are usually referenced using pointer (ie. `QWidget*`). If Qt used operators for accessing properties, it would be very easy to end up using the indexing operator on the pointer Consider the following:

```
void doSomethingWithProperty(QWidget* widget) {
   auto& propertyValue = widget[0];
}
```

`propertyValue` here would not be the result of the indexing operator on `QWidget`/`QObject` if there was one because we can treat pointers like arrays in C/C++ (note that this is sometimes considered a bad practice). It would be a reference to the widget. To instead call the operator on the type, you would need something like `(*widget)[0]` which is not nice to write.

Maybe you use strings for the operator parameter... but then it isn't clear to me what the operator does. Qt objects have child objects. Does `(*widget)["thing"]` return a property named `thing` or does if find a child object named thing? It is not obvious to me which one it should be.

Comment: The arguments are more than sufficient, thank you!